# Is it ok to use ASP.NET MVC on production?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Since ASP.NET MVC is still in beta, is it OK to use it in a production environment?

It's gotta be OK since StackOverflow and many other sites use it, right?  I've been wanting to try it out, but I know if I propose actually using it on production I will get resistance because it's still in beta.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MVC is not in beta anymore.

And yes, it's ok to use MVC in production.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC 1.0 is good for production (its not BETA), we currently have a production server with full MVC and jQuery for the client side magic, no problems at all.

There are some interesting public sites like this one (stackoverflow) and codeplex.com, and people think that were written in ruby on rails or something similar, because of the clean URL, RESTfull approach and some other stuff you don't spec to be a traditional ASP like site, and indeed is ASP but MVC 1.0.

Comment: At this moment asp.net mvc 2.0 is BETA, and not recommended for production environments.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.NET MVC 1.0 is not in beta. MVC 2.0 is in beta 2 stage. If you test your application properly, both should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mVC/) is not in beta as of v1.0.  V2.0 will be released with VS2010 and .NET4.